# Is there a cross-platform way to set build type of project generated with cmake?

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, build-type

CMake and VS seem to have a rather strange relationship. I am trying to figure out why setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` doesn't affect the build of the generated Visual Studio solution and project that are part of it.

For example (using CMake GUI) I have the following in my `CMakeLists.txt` (it's purely for debugging purposes):

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not set. Fallback to default: Release\nSupported build types:\n   - Release\n   - Debug")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()
```

Since I am not setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in the GUI, the variable is empty and hence internally set to `Release`.

However after the configuration step is over in the table with set variables (GUI) I clearly see

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE  /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE    /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
```

among other variables that have values indicating I have clearly configured a `Debug` build.

Beside manually setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` etc. on a platform to platform basis is there actually a way to set the build type in an easy way, preferably just by changing the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `/DNDEBUG`, this actually indicates a `Release` build.

This define means "Not debug" and makes calls to `assert()` functions to be a no-op. More info [here](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.2).

All other flags control optimization levels, and values of `O2` and `Ob2` are also used mainly for non-Debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` has no effect on the VS project is the fact that in contrast to the "Unix Makefile" generator the VS generator is a multi configuration generator. This means every project you set up with the VS generator provides multiple configurations at the same time (Relase, Debug, ect.), but setting up the same project with the "Unix Makefile" generator you need to decide on one configuration (or use the default one).

The decision on the configuration has been "delayed" for multi-configuration generators. For a single configuration generator you use

```
cmake --build <dir>
```

to build your project, for a multi configuration project you use

```
cmake --build <dir> --config <config>
```

(`<dir>` being replaced with the build directory and `<config>` being replaced with `Debug`, `Release` or one of the other available configurations in the commands.)